# PowerShell passing parameter with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to find the correct syntax to pass 2 variables from the CALL-script to the execution script in order to have it executed on the remote server. I tried single quotes, double quotes, brackets, .. nothing I can fiind passes the `$Target` and `$OlderThanDays` parameters to the script.

Thank you for your help.

**The CALL-Script:**

```
#================= VARIABLES ==================================================
$ScriptDir = "\\Server\Scripts"
#================= BODY =======================================================
# Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER1 -FilePath $ScriptDir\"Auto_Clean.ps1"         

Invoke-Command -FilePath .\Test.ps1 -ComputerName SERVER01 -ArgumentList {-Target ´E:\Share\Dir1\Dir2´,-OlderThanDays ´10´}
```

**The execution Script:**

```
#================= PARAMETERS =================================================
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
   [string]$Target,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
   [string]$OlderThanDays
)

#================= BODY =======================================================
# Set start time & logname
$StartTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()
$LogName = "Auto_Clean.log"

# Format header for log
$TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()+" |"
$Header = "`n$TimeStamp Deleting files and folders that are older than $OlderThanDays days:`n"
Write-Output  "$Header" # to console
Out-File $Target\$LogName -inputobject $Header -Append # to log
# PS 2.0 Workaround (`tee-object -append`) // PS 4.0: `Write-Output "`nDeleting folders that are older than $OlderThanDays days:`n" | Tee-Object $LogFile -Append` 

# Remove files older than
Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Exclude $LogName -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$OlderThanDays) } | ForEach {
        $Item = $_.FullName
        Remove-Item $Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Timestamp = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+" | "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()      
        # If folder can't be removed
        if (Test-Path $Item)
            { "$Timestamp | FAILLED: $Item (IN USE)" } 
        else
            { "$Timestamp | REMOVED: $Item" }  
        } | Out-File $Target\$LogName -Append
        # PS 4.0: ´| Tee-Object $Target\$LogName -Append` # Output folder names to console & logfile at the same time

# Remove empty folders   
while (Get-ChildItem $Target -recurse | where {!@(Get-ChildItem -force $_.FullName)} | Test-Path) {
    Get-ChildItem $Target -recurse | where {!@(Get-ChildItem -force $_.FullName)} | Remove-Item
}             

# Format footer
$EndTime = (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()+", "+(Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()
$TimeTaken = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime

Write-Output ($Footer = @"

   Start Time          : $StartTime
   End Time            : $EndTime
   Total Runtime       : $TimeTaken
$("-"*79)
"@)

# Write footer to log
Out-File -FilePath $Target\$LogName -Append -InputObject $Footer

# Clean up variables
$Target=$StartTime=$EndTime=$OlderThanDays = $null
```

The execution script:

Comment: can you try with `-argumentlist @(´E:\Share\Dir1\Dir2´,10)`

Comment: As you suggested I tried `Invoke-Command -FilePath .\Test.ps1 -ComputerName SERVER1 -ArgumentList @(´E:\Share\Dir1\Dir2´,10)`but no luck. PowerShell complains about the _comma_ separator. I also tried `-ArgumentList @(´E:\Share\Dir1\Dir2´,´10´)`, but the same problem.

Comment: use `"` instead of `´`

Comment: Yes, this does the trick `-ArgumentList @("E:\Share\Dir1\Dir2","10")`, but it deletes all files instead of taking care of the `$OlderThanDays`variable. Even when I put `Write-Output $OlderThanDays`in the execution script, it displays nothing in the console. But `Write-Output $Target`does give the correct output. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it by changing `[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)`to `[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)` Thank you for your help :)

Comment: i write this as an answer if you want to accept it so your question will not appear unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have got to use `"` or `'` but not `´` :

```
-argumentlist @('E:\Share\Dir1\Dir2',10)
```